# Int and String F#

Tags: string, f#, int

I have a function in F#, where I take an `int` value and return the `int` as a `string`.

```
let inttostring (x:int):string = 
    ""+x
```

I can't get ToString to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't this work? `let inttostring (i: int): string = i.ToString()`

Comment: Voting to close. If you don't know F# is strongly typed or about `object.ToString` it's time to read the docs.

Comment: It's not about strongly typed. C# is strongly typed, but it has implicit conversion, so you can add integers to strings. This wouldn't be my preferred approach in C#, but it would compile. I don't think its necessarily a RTFM moment if someone didn't know F# doesn't do implicit casts.

Comment: @JoelMueller: If he wanted to know _why_ this doesn't work, or why F# doesn't have implicit conversion like C#, those are reasonable questions. The problem is he said he can't manage to convert an int to string, which suggests he hasn't even done a cursory search.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Empty string `""` isn't compatible with `x` which is of `int` type. You can use

```
let int2String x = sprintf "%i" x
```

or

```
let int2String (x: int) = string x
```

Comment: ...or `i.ToString()` or `Convert.ToString(i)` or `String.Concat("", i)`...

Comment: It's probably worth saying that for new joiners to F# that types are implicitly converted between each other (which is what pad is saying above). You need to explicitly convert from one type to another to get the code to compile.

Comment: @Chris: I believe you mean are *not*.

Comment: @Daniel: my apologies, you are completely correct. F# types are **not** implicitly converted like they are in other languages (e.g. C#)